# Wide vs. Narrow datasets - Machine Learning question

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection, data-transformation, regularization

Machine Learning questions here.

Suppose I have a dataset of labeled 1,000 records, and 200 features - and I use R to test out a neural net or random forest's abilities to predict a certain feature.

What, if anything, should change if I instead have 1,000 features, and 200 records? Is feature selection my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is feature selection my only option?

**NO**. With 200 observations and 1000 variables, the variables must necessarily be heavily correlated *in the sample*, (even if the population variables might be unrelated.)  But feature selection (based on the sample, that is) is not a good solution. A better solution is often *regularization*, see for instance [Intuitive understanding of regularization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83216/intuitive-understanding-of-regularization)  or  [Problem specific regularization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23468/problem-specific-regularization), or search this site.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the `wide vs narrow data` is just used to classify the presentation of data: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data

A neural net is mostly a advanced form of fitting a linear fit such as

y =a*x+b.

To fit the above equation you would need atleast 2 data points. Imagine what would happen, if you just had 1 data point.

Your case of having 1000 features and 200 data points is similar to having 1 data point to fit a linear equation.